# How to check if ringtone is changed successfully to what I set?

Tags: android, ringtonemanager

That's how I change the ringtone:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, ringtoneUri)
```

How can I check if the ringtone is changed with my sound file?

```
 private static void setActualRingtone(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri ringtoneUri, int type) {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, ringtoneUri);
        if(RingtoneManager.isDefault(ringtoneUri)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Operation successful=)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Operation failed=)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with the following function:

```
isDefault(ringtoneUri)
```

For more information please refer the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html).

Comment: That returns false but the ringtone is set as what I gave.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it like that:

```
 if ((RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type)).equals(ringtoneUri)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.operation_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```